# How do you set a selected item in an HTML dropdown by name, not by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML combobox which contains unique options.  For example, a `country` dropdown which contains `country_id` as a value and `country name` as text.

Is there any way using jQuery or JavaScript to let me set the selected item using the `country name` not the `country_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("option:contains('COUNTRY NAME HERE')").attr('selected','selected');
```

something like that?

Comment: dude it was really great and it works perfect but I am greaty instead of contains is there any other key word match the word as its  coz I have some names similar to each other

Answer (score 0):

This links discusses some options:
http://www.daftlogic.com/information-programmatically-preselect-dropdown-using-javascript.htm

Answer (score -1):

You can do write like below:

```
$("option:selected").text()
```

to obtain the text given for the option

Comment: -, this is for retrieving not for setting